# How to create spawn of boxes like in Party Panic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am new to Unity and I can’t understand how to make a script that will make boxes spawn like in this game. I tried to make it myself, but my boxes are spawn only once.

(in this video shows what should happen) https://youtu.be/rvyn5wVLYek?t=77

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
 [SerializeField] private GameObject _box;
 [SerializeField] [Range(0, 5)] private int _minBoxes;
 [SerializeField] [Range(1, 25)] private int _maxBoxes;
 [SerializeField] private float _spawnHeight;
 void Start() {
    var size = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds.size.x * transform.localScale.x;
    var boxes = Random.Range(_minBoxes, _maxBoxes + 1);
    var step = size / boxes;

    for (int i = 1; i < boxes; i++) {
        Instantiate(_box, transform.position + new Vector3(step * i - size / 2f,  _spawnHeight), Quaternion.identity);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any supplementary code to provide us with? i.e. Code you have tried.

Comment: @NickJuelich I added

Comment: @Bean5 Music Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to stackoverflow.

From what im seeing in the video u want a box to spawn in a certain x position with a certain scale, here is the code I came up with.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoxSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject box;
    public float minXpos, maxXpos;
    public float timeBetweenBoxes;
    void Start()
    {
        //starts the loop for spawning boxes
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBox());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnBox()
    {
        //get a random position on the x axis
        Vector3 boxPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(minXpos, maxXpos), 0, 0);

        //spawn the box
        Instantiate(box, boxPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));

        //let the code wait a certain time
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenBoxes);

        StartCoroutine(SpawnBox());
    }
}
```

put this script on a random gameobject and make a [Prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) of the box gameobject. Drag that prefab on to the gameobject/script.

Make a new script and put this code on to that script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Box : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float minSize = 0.5f; //minimum size
    private float maxSize = 2; //maximum size
    private float moveSpeed = 5;
    void Start()
    {
        //changes the size of the object to random values
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(minSize, maxSize), Random.Range(minSize, maxSize), Random.Range(minSize, maxSize));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //moves the box in -z axis
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);


        //destroys gameobject after a number of seconds (OPTIONAL BUT RECOMMENDED)
        //Destroy(gameObject, 10);
    }
}
```

Place this script on the prefab that u created and drag it in to the assets folder to save the prefab, reference the prefab to the Spawner gameobject and it should work.

[image: Final result]

if u want to boxes to move physically add a Rigidbody component to it